# Select multiple rows multiple times from a numpy array at once avoiding loops

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I am looking for a way to select multiple rows from a numpy array multiple times given an array of indexes.

Given `M` and `indexes`, I would like to get `N` avoiding for loop, since it is slow for big dimensions.

```
import numpy as np
M = np.array([[1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
              [1, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
indexes = np.array([[True, False, False, True],
                    [False, True, True, True],
                    [False, False, True, False],
                    [True, True, False, True]])
N = [M[index] for index in indexes]


Out: 
[array([[1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 1]]),
 array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 1]]),
 array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1]]),
 array([[1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 1]])]
```

Comment: The fact that you get a list of arrays that differ in shape strongly suggests that this list comprehension is the best you can do.

Comment: Numpy is usually at its best when handling homogeneous data while your expected output is not. Loop seems like the best choice here.

Comment: @hpaul is list comprehension really better than `np.split` here?

Answer (score 1):

We can use advantage that output data is homogenous in at least one dimension.

```
x, y = np.where(indexes)
split_idx = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(x))+1
output = np.split(M[y], split_idx)
```

Sample run:

```
>>> x
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3], dtype=int32)
>>> y
array([0, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 0, 1, 3], dtype=int32)
>>> split_idx
array([2, 5, 6], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: For this small example, the straightforward list comprehension is faster.  But the alternatives may scale differently.   `split` has to loop as well, taking multiple slices.  Scaling may depend on the number of rows versus columns.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach, that uses broadcasting, and a different way of identifying the split points:

```
b_shape = (indexes.shape[0],) + M.shape  # New shape for broadcasted M. Here, (4,4,5)
M_b = np.broadcast_to(M, b_shape)        # Broadcasted M with the new shape.
                                         # (it uses views instead of replicating data)
r,c = np.nonzero(indexes)
result_joined = M_b[r,c,:]                             # The stack of all the selected rows from M
split_points = np.cumsum(np.sum(indexes, axis=1))[:-1] # Identify where to split.
result_split = np.split (result_merged, split_points)  # Final result, obtained by splitting.
```

**Output:**

```
[array([[1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 1]]),
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 1]]),
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1]]),
array([[1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 1]])]

print (result_split)
```